# Show that if $g(f(x)) $ is one-to-one and $f$ is onto, then $g$ is one-to-one

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I've attempted to prove this proposition and would appreciate some critique. N.B: I've taken for granted that $g \circ f$ injective $\rightarrow f$ injective.

Specifically, for functions $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$ show that ($g \circ f$ injective $\wedge $ $f$ onto) $\rightarrow g$ injective. I tried to prove the contrapositive statement $\neg$($g$ injective) $\rightarrow$ $\neg$($g \circ f$ injective $\wedge $ $f$ onto) $\leftrightarrow$ ($\neg g \circ f$ injective $\vee \neg f$ onto) $\leftrightarrow$ ($\neg g \circ f$ injective $\wedge $ $f$ onto) $\vee$ ($g \circ f$ injective $\wedge $ $\neg f$ onto).

1. We can have $\neg g$ injective with $g \circ f$ injective if $\neg f$ onto because then there may exist $b \in B$ s.t. $f(a) \neq b\forall a\in A$ so the case might be that there are no $a_1 \neq a_2 \in A$ s.t. $(g \circ f)(a_1) = (g \circ f)(a_2)\leftrightarrow (g \circ f)$ is injective.
2. We can have $\neg g$ injective with $f$ onto if $\neg g \circ f$ injective because then there exists $b_1 \neq b_2 \in B$ s.t. $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$ with corresponding $a_1 \neq a_2 \in A$ s.t. $g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2)) \leftrightarrow \neg g \circ f$ injective.
3. However, we cannot have $\neg g$ injective $\wedge$ $[g \circ f$ injective $\wedge f$ onto$]$ because, by the injectivity of $g$, there will exist $b_1 \neq b_2$ with corresponding $a_1 \neq a_2$, since $f$ is well-defined, s.t. $(g \circ f)(a_1) = (g \circ f)(a_2)$ rendering $g \circ f$ not injective.

Q.E.D.

A secondary question, which should perhaps be considered separately, is about how I've (correctly, I hope) manipulated the logical statement of the question. I've considered $\neg$(g injective) $\rightarrow$ $\neg$($g \circ f$ injective $\wedge $ $f$ onto) like an 'equation' with $\rightarrow$ acting like $=$. Then, intuitively, I thought I could separately operate on both sides with ($\wedge g \circ f$ injective) and ($\wedge f$ onto) to get the two separate statements $\neg g$ injective $\wedge g \circ f$ injective $\rightarrow \neg f$ onto and $\neg g$ injective $\wedge f$ onto $\rightarrow \neg g \circ f$ injective which I attempted to show in parts 1. and 2. above. Is this valid reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating things; your argument is a bit hard to follow, and there are too many symbols. Let's try going back to the definitions.

---

Let $f\colon A \to B$ and $g\colon B \to C$ be functions such that $g \circ f$ is one-to-one and $f$ is onto. We want to show that $g$ is one-to-one. To this end, choose any $b_1, b_2 \in B$ such that $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$. It remains to show that $b_1 = b_2$.

Indeed, since $f$ is onto, we know that there exist $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $f(a_1) = b_1$ and $f(a_2) = b_2$. But then since $g \circ f$ is one-to-one and since:
$$
(g \circ f)(a_1) = g(f(a_1)) = g(b_1) = g(b_2) = g(f(a_2)) = (g \circ f)(a_2)
$$
it follows that $a_1 = a_2$. Hence, since $f$ is a well-defined function, we conclude that:
$$
b_1 = f(a_1) = f(a_2) = b_2
$$
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$